# can't push UINavigationItem on UINavigationBar in Swift4

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

We create navigationBar with code and set navigationItem for that navigationBar.

However, pressing navigationItem does not react.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

    let navBar: UINavigationBar = {
        let navBar = UINavigationBar()
        navBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 44, width: view.frame.width, height: navBar.frame.height)
        navBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
        let navItem = UINavigationItem()
        let saveButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .save, target: self, action: #selector(saveBook))
        navItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton
        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .cancel, target: self, action: #selector(cancel))
        navItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton
        navItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
        navItem.leftBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = true
        navItem.title = "書籍追加"
        navBar.pushItem(navItem, animated: true)
        return navBar
    }()
    view.addSubview(navBar)
```

Comment: Any reason you are doing all of this manually instead of using a `UINavigationController` and pushing view controllers as needed?

Comment: Yes I am! But I don't know the reason..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly this code is not right as the frame is still CGRect.zero. So you are setting the height to 0. You did not get what you want.

not right here:

```
  navBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 44, width: view.frame.width, height: navBar.frame.height)
```

If you add the code, you will know what I mean as you cannot see the navBar?:

```
    navBar.clipsToBounds = true
    view.addSubview(navBar)
```

you may try:

```
  navBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 44, width: view.frame.width, height: 44)
```

Comment: Thank you!! it's solved!! But why don't moved setting the "navBar.frame.height"?

Comment: Because navBar.frame has a height 0 after "let navBar = UINavigationBar()"